# How return $.event.trigger result

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

How to return the result of the work caused by the event?
Example:

```
var res = $.event.trigger({
  type: 'my_event_name',
  element: el
});
console.dir(res);

$("body").on('my_event_name', function(e)
{
   return save_data(e.element);
});
```

There is a code that performs the default action, if there is no event handler. If there is an event handler, you must perform the work he and the default code should not work.
Example pseudocode:

```
var res = $.event.trigger({
  type: 'my_event_name',
  element: el
});

if (res)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    // default action code
}
```

Comment: You can't return data from an event handler, so basically you can't

Comment: Now you'd have better to post a concrete sample of why would you need this kind of behaviour

Comment: There is a code that performs the default action, if there is no event handler. If there is an event handler, you must perform the work he and the default code should not work.

Comment: That comment doesn't make a lot of sense. Please update question with a full description in proper sentences of what it is you are trying to do

Comment: how do you know whether the trigger? if he does not return results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass data back in the result, but you can check for `e.isDefaultPrevented()` and use `e.preventDefault()` as required in the function

e.g.

```
$("body").on('my_event_name', function(e, params)
{
   if (save_data(params.element)){
       e.preventdefault();
   }
});
```

and use like this:

```
var evt = $.Event('my_event_name');
$.event.trigger( evt, {
  element: el
});

if (evt.isDefaultPrevented())
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    // default action code
}
```

*Note: I may have the logic reversed as your example is incomplete :)*

One alternative (which actually *will* send data), is to generate a second custom event, passing the data along, but this would require a separate handler for the result after starting the process.

```
$("body").on('my_event_name', function(e)
{
   if (save_data(e.element)){
      $.event.trigger({
         type: 'my_other_event_name',
         data: trueOrSomethingElse
      });
   }
});
```

and listen with:

```
$("body").on('my_other_event_name', function(e)
{
    console.log(e.data);
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDefaultPrevented' of undefined

Comment: @djmartini: Updated. If you need more details, please provide a JSFiddle sufficient to show the problem/solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You're trying to use events in a synchronous fashion. This will not work. You cannot "wait" for an event to happen when you run a function.</s>

EDIT: I foo'd up with this answer. From **TrueBlueAussie**
"The custom events shown are not asynchronous. They are simply broadcast to the target element, and bubble to its ancestors, then immediately return. That is why you can use e.isDefaultPrevented() on a custom event."

You may want something like this.

```
// trigger your event somewhere, maybe in another function
var res = $.event.trigger({
  type: 'my_event_name',
  element: el
});

$("body").on('my_event_name', function(e)
{
    // when your event fires, it will fire doMyEvent()
    doMyEvent(e.element)
});

function doMyEvent(eventData){
    if (eventData)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // default action code
    }
}
```

Comment: The custom events shown are *not* asynchronous. They are simply broadcast to the target element, and bubble to its ancestors, then immediately return. That is why you can use `e.isDefaultPrevented()` on a custom event.

Comment: Apologies, I should probably use better wording. I'll edit my answer.